# ADO.NET using .where<> clause

Tags: ado.net

I'm using ADO.Net to access a database. But right now, I'm trying to recover some information, but I can't remember how to use the `.where<>`clause.

Here the code:

```
string sql = "Id = '" + identifier + "'";
USER u = db.USER.Where(sql).First<USER>();
```

Where `db`is the Entity Model, but I fail to remember how to use this `Where<>` clause...

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use lambda expression :

```
User u=db.USER.Where(x=>x.Id==identifier).First();
```

or you can write your query this way :

```
User u=from us in db.Users Where us.Id==identifier select us ;
```

and here is another way to use lambda expressionn :

```
User u=db.Users.First(x=>x.Id==identifier);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `LINQ`

```
USER u = db.USER.Where(x => x.Id == identifier).First<USER>();
```

This post on [Parameterized IN clauses with ADO.NET and LINQ](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/116/Parameterized-IN-clauses-with-ADO.NET-and-LINQ) might be helpful for reference

Comment: Hummm yes... sorry... what's the X?

Comment: x is just a variable, (they always seem to use x in examples!), I would have used `u` or `user` but you've already used them in your code and I didn't want to mix things up there.